# ruby get random pic from google

Tags: ruby, api, rubygems, discord, bots

I'm searching for a little code. I'm using the lastest version of ruby.

Im working on a bot for discord, what sends random pictures in a text-channel.
For example:
The bot is searching google picture with the keyword 'sun'. And then he should take a random pic from the 1000000000000 of results and send it in the discord.

I have search for a google api, I have search for a code that is making this but nothing works.
I think I'm sitting here for like 2 hours and every code I tried failed.

So yeah, hope you could help me out.

LG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running this in `irb`:

```rb
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

puts "Type in a search term below:\n\n"

# get user search term
search_term = gets.chomp

# construct EN google image search results page
url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=#{search_term}&hl=en&tbm=isch"

# scrape google images
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(open(url).read)

# store all image urls on the first search page in an array
imgs = doc.search('img').map(&:attributes).map { |node| node['src'].value }

# filter bad urls
imgs.select { |url| url.match(/https/) }

# print and return random image url
image = imgs[rand(0..imgs.length-1)]
p image
```

Of course the Google image API will be better than scraping. If you could edit your comment and provide your script code and the JSON structure returned by the Google API it will be easier for us to debug it for you.